# Custom date format for datepicker Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Can anyone guide me for formatting date in Bootstrap-datePicker?

Here is my codes at html:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Check in" id="checkin" name="checkin">
<input type="text" placeholder="Check out" id="checkout" name="checkout">
```

and at my JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#checkin').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e){
            (e.viewMode=='days') ? $(this).datepicker('hide') : '';
        });
        $('#checkout').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e){
            (e.viewMode=='days') ? $(this).datepicker('hide') : '';
        });

    });
</script>
```

I've to use that version because I want it to hide after selecting the date. Other versions doesn't work. So, where should I put the format: dd.mm.yyy thing?

thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this out, this might help you as well
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Please don't provide [link only answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 1):

This is noted in the [docs](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
 });
```

You can format the string   `mm/dd/yyyy` using a combination of `d, dd, m, mm, yy, yyy`.

Answer (score 0):

**You may use this kind of code for hiding date picker**
Check your conditions accordingly and use. I have added some conditions here.

---

```
$('#documentDate').datepicker({
        format: 'dd-mm-yy',
        startDate: '+d'
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        var today =new Date();
        if(ev.date.getDate() == today.getDate() && ev.date.getMonth()== today.getMonth() && ev.date.getYear()== today.getYear()){
            $('#documentDate').val('');
        }else if(ev.date.valueOf() < today.valueOf()){
            $('#documentDate').val('');
        }else{
           $(this).blur();
           $(this).datepicker('hide');
        }
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });
    $("#documentDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
              $('#documentDate').datepicker('hide');
          }   
    });
```